# PERT pessimistic formula and standard deviation

Tags: distributions, estimation, standard-deviation

I've just read the book "Software Estimation" written by Steve McConnell. I have very little knowledge in statistics.

The well known PERT formula to estimate the time of a task is:

```
expectedCase = (bestCase + 4 * mostLikelyCase + worstCase) / 6
```

In this case, the PERT standard deviation is approximated by `(worstCase - bestCase) / 6`.

However, the book mention a "pessimistic PERT formula" for expected time:

```
expectedCase = (bestCase + 3 * mostLikelyCase + 2 * worstCase) / 6
```

In this case, can the standard deviation be computed the same way, with `(worstCase - bestCase) / 6`? Or must it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

What McConnell proposes is simply a different point on the exact same distribution. The further you move your choice to the right of the distribution the more certainty you choose. But you do not change the underlying distribution.

[image]

That should not be confused with the modified Pert suggested by Vose (2000) which leads to a different means and variances ([see also here](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/PERTdistribution.php)):

$$ expectedCase = \frac{(bestCase + \lambda * mostLikelyCase + worstCase)} {\lambda+2} $$

In the standard case, $\lambda$ is set to `4`. You can choose a different shape of the Pert distribution by changing $\lambda$. Vose suggest that a subject matter expert may choose lambda when the think that a flatter or more peaked probability distribution fits his/her opinion more accurately.

Going back to standard Pert it is also interesting to note that the 6-sigma standard deviation formula `range/6` that you quoted is only approximately accurate under certain assumptions and should be avoided when these do not hold (Farnum and Stanton, 1987; [see again here](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/PERTdistribution.php)). The condition is: `Mode + 0.13(Max - Mode) < Mode < Mode + 0.13(Max - Mode)` with `Mode` being the `mostLikelyCase`. The most likely case should not lie less that 13% of the range from either the best or worst case.